# Why Do i See 2 Aarsvc services running in task manager

Tags: windows-11

I Have Windoes 11 and when i go and check task manager there are 2 AarSvc services running
AarSvc is stopped and a wierd like AarSvc_220ca0 is active please help me it wasn't there before i did not install any apps pls help me!

Answer (score 0):

The first is a normal "global" service, but the second is a "per-user" service – there's a copy of that service for each Windows user account (with a different suffix for each user).

- The Old New Thing (Microsoft Developer Blogs): [What are these duplicate services whose names differ just by random characters at the end?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201229-00/?p=104612)